# cant start SSIS service on sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server, ssis

In Sql Server Configuration Manager I Sql Server Integration Services has status stopped, when I try to start it aftger few seconds there is an error message: The request failed or the server did not respond in a timely fashion.

Where the problme can be ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the event log on the server. It should give you a reason. I've had this before when I've applied a service pack to the database engine but not selected to upgrade SSIS and then it complains about mismatched version. Also might be an issue with the account the service is running under.